# What folders does the "all my files" finder view pull from?

Tags: finder, time-machine, filesystem, trash

A relative of mine managed to delete all of the files under "All my files."  I am restoring from a recent time machine backup, but am trying to figure out which folders need to be restored.  So far I have:

1. Desktop folder
2. Downloads
3. Documents

What else shows up in this view?  iTunes music and iPhoto pictures both seem to have been excluded from the reaping.

(Seriously, they dragged everything you can see in "all my files" to the trash and emptied the trash.  The entire skeleton of the folder structure is still there, but the files are gone.  Files that do not show up under "all my files," such as applications iPhoto photos escaped the harvest. Thank god for time machine, otherwise the situation would be horrifying instead of hilarious).

Comment: Well if anyone else is looking, the search scope is `kMDQueryScopeMyFiles`. No idea what that means.

Comment: A little more looking and it appears to be a private framework (`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework`)…sigh…

Comment: @0942v8653 of course, lol.  Fortunately, I think all the important stuff was in Desktop and Documents, but I want to be complete.